# Handling rate limits when using an API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, hubspot

In my Laravel application I am using the HubSpot API extensively to perform various actions. I have read in the documentation that you can make 150 requests per each 10 second period.

To monitor this HubSpot provide the following Headers when making any API call.

```
"X-HubSpot-RateLimit-Daily" => array:1 [▶]
"X-HubSpot-RateLimit-Daily-Remaining" => array:1 [▶]
"X-HubSpot-RateLimit-Interval-Milliseconds" => array:1 [▶]
"X-HubSpot-RateLimit-Max" => array:1 [▶]
"X-HubSpot-RateLimit-Remaining" => array:1 [▶]
"X-HubSpot-RateLimit-Secondly" => array:1 [▶]
"X-HubSpot-RateLimit-Secondly-Remaining" => array:1 [▶]
```

In my application I am making use of Laravel's Http Client, which is basically just a wrapper for Guzzle.

In order to adhere to the rate limits would I literally just have to wrap an if statement around every request?

Here's an example:

$endpoint = 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/owners/';

```
$response = Http::get($endpoint, [
    'limit' => 100,
    'hapikey' => config('hubspot.api_key'),
]);
```

In this case the `$response` would contain the Headers but would there be a way to effectively use them, as surely I would only know what the rates were once I'd made the API call?

I ask as I have to pull down 1,000 + deals and then update some records, but this would definately go over the API limit. For reference, here is the command I wrote.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Events\DealImportedFromHubspot;
use App\Hubspot\PipelineHubspot;
use App\Models\Deal;
use App\Models\DealStage;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class ImportHubspotDeals extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'import:hubspot-deals
        {--force : Whether we should force the command}
    ';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Import Deal objects from the HubSpot API in bulk.';

    /**
     * An array to store imported Deals
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $importedDeals = [];

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->line('Importing Pipelines & Deal Stages from HubSpot API...');

        PipelineHubspot::import();

        $this->line('Importing Deals from HubSpot API...');

        $this->getDealsFromHubspot();

        $this->line('Found ' . count($this->importedDeals) . ' Deals to import');

        if ($this->option('force')) {
            $this->doImport();
        } else {
            if ($this->confirm('Do you want to import these deals? (yes|no)', false)) {
                $this->doImport();
            } else {
                $this->line('Process aborted');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Grab Deals from Hubspot by calling the Deals API and looping through the paginated data
     *
     * @param int    $limit: the number of deals per page
     * @param string $next:  the link to the next page of results
     */
    private function getDealsFromHubspot(?int $limit = 100, string $next = null)
    {
        $endpoint = 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals';

        $properties = [
            'limit' => $limit,
            'properties' => implode(',', Deal::HUBSPOT_DEAL_PROPERTIES),
            'hapikey' => config('hubspot.api_key'),
            'associations' => 'engagements',
        ];

        // If there's another page, append the after parameter.
        if ($next) {
            $properties['after'] = $next;
        }

        $response = Http::get($endpoint, $properties);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            $data = $response->json();

            // If there are results, get them.
            if (isset($data['results'])) {
                foreach ($data['results'] as $hubspotDeal) {
                    $this->importedDeals[] = $hubspotDeal['properties'];
                }
            }

            // If there's paginate we need to call the function on itself
            if (isset($data['paging']['next']['link'])) {
                $this->getDealsFromHubspot(null, $data['paging']['next']['after']);
            }
        }

        $response->json();
    }

    /**
     * Pull the Deal data in order to create a Deal model.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    private function syncDeal(array $data)
    {
        $excludedDealStages = DealStage::excludeFromDealImport()->pluck('hubspot_id');

        if ($excludedDealStages->contains($data['dealstage'])) {
            return false;
        }

        $deal = Deal::updateOrCreate([
            'hubspot_id' => $data['hs_object_id'],
        ], [
            'name' => $data['dealname'],
            'deal_stage_id' => $data['dealstage'],
            'hubspot_owner_id' => $data['hubspot_owner_id'] ?? null,
        ]);

        event(new DealImportedFromHubspot($deal));

        return $deal;
    }

    /**
     * Create and increment a nice progress bar as we import deals.
     */
    private function doImport()
    {
        $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($this->importedDeals));

        $bar->start();

        foreach ($this->importedDeals as $deal) {
            $this->syncDeal($deal);

            $bar->advance();
        }

        $bar->finish();

        $this->newLine(2);

        $this->line('Successfully imported ' . count($this->importedDeals) . ' Deals from HubSpot.');
    }
}
```

Building on this `event(new DealImportedFromHubspot($deal));` also makes an API call back to HubSpot to add the URL of the portal it had just been pulled into.

In this situation I'm thinking I either need to treat the deal importing as its own job, or add in some kind of rate limiter.

Would it be bad practise just to use `sleep(10)` to get around the rate limiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a [`Queue`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues).

You can define your own [rate limiter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#rate-limiting) on the `Queue`, but the correct solution is probably to extend `ShouldQueue` and run `$this->fail()` when you get a response saying your request has been throttled.

Comment: So in your opinion, would you split the console command i pasted into separate jobs? I thought a recursive method was a good idea until I realised that if there were enough it would go over the rate limit just from grabbing data.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. It sort of depends on how often you expect to hit the rate limit and how long you expect your command to be running.

Comment: See I think with this mass pulling, I'm not likely to do it often because once they're in you can check each individually.